# Sharepoint Online SPFx error on all webparts : Something went wrong -> Mismatched anonymous define() module

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

Error on sharepoint online SPFX webparts as,

Something went wrong -> Mismatched anonymous define() module

[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304837/sharepoint-online-every-spfx-web-parts-get-this-error-something-went-wrong) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371918/mismatched-anonymous-define-module) if it helps.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, i checked both the post but not sure what exactly is causing this error and what fix to try. All the spfx webparts have the same issue.